# Why is this type_traits code giving me an integer-to-pointer cast warning?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Without going into too much detail, I've created a variadic template function which does different things depending on the type of its template parameters. I simplified the implementation into a really simple console print example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

void print(const char *chars) {
    printf("%s", chars);
}

template<typename FirstType, typename ... OtherTypes>
inline void print(FirstType first, OtherTypes... others);

template<typename ... OtherTypes>
inline void print(const char *chars, OtherTypes... others) {
    print(chars);
    print(" ");

    if (sizeof...(others) == 0) {
        print("\r\n");
    }
    else {
        print(others...);
    }
}

template<typename FirstType, typename ... OtherTypes>
inline void print(FirstType first, OtherTypes... others) {
    char buffer[10];
    const char *format = nullptr;

    if (std::is_same<int, FirstType>::value) {
        format = "%d";
    }
    else if (std::is_same<char, FirstType>::value) {
        format = "%c";
    }
    else if (std::is_pointer<FirstType>::value && (std::is_same<char*, FirstType>::value || std::is_same<const char*, FirstType>::value)) {
        print((const char *) first, others...);
        return;
    }

    if (format != nullptr) {
        snprintf(buffer, 10, format, first);
    }

    print((const char *) buffer, others...);
}

int main() {
    print("this is an example:", 'X');

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I call the variadic function with a `const char*` and a `char`. It works correctly, however the trouble is that the compiler gives me a warning:

```
[Timur@Timur-Zenbook tm]$ g++ tm.cpp -Wall -Wextra -o tm
tm.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void print(FirstType, OtherTypes ...) [with FirstType = char; OtherTypes = {}]’:
tm.cpp:24:14:   required from ‘void print(const char*, OtherTypes ...) [with OtherTypes = {char}]’
tm.cpp:52:37:   required from here
tm.cpp:40:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
         print((const char *) first, others...);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The warning comes for the `char` argument, as if the function incorrectly determined the type of `char` to be the same as `const char*` and therefore the code path for `const char*` were triggered.

Why am I getting this warning and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I getting this warning

The code in that branch is still *instantiated* when `FirstType` is `char`, even though that branch will never actually be executed.

> how do I fix it?

Move code that only makes sense for some type(s) out to an overload or specialized trait, so that it isn't compiled in the first place for non-matching types.

The simplest change is to remove the `else if(std::is_pointer...` branch entirely, and add this overload, which has the same effect:

```
template<typename ... OtherTypes>
inline void print(char *chars, OtherTypes... others) {
    print((const char *)chars, others...);
}
```

Comment: In this specific case, it will be assigned a value, as the format will be "%c".  It's certainly a mistake waiting to happen though; and would be better to assert format != nullptr.

Comment: I'm not sure you're looking at the same problem as me - certainly, there are other quality issues in this example code.

Comment: `if constexpr` will make this easier

Comment: Agreed (and that would also replace the remaining overloads with static branches)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So basically you are saying that it is better to add an overload than to use `type_traits` this way?

Comment: @UKMonkey If you guys have any specific suggestions, those are more than welcome, but keep in mind that this is just a dumbed-down piece of example code. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Venemo: Google it!